# Triggering the first list item while using List with map in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am displaying list item through map function. But I want the list item to automatically trigger itself and show something for instance i am just using console.log for that. So the first list item should automatically trigger it's onClick function. Is there anyway to acheive this in react?

...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [data, useData] = useState([
    { list: "appelllll" },
    { list: "ballllslsss" },
    { list: "cattsssssss" },
    { list: "dogssssss" },
    { list: "eggssss" },
    { list: "fatssssssssssssssssssss" },
    { list: "goatssssssssssssssss" },
    { list: "heloooooooooooooooooo" },
    { list: "ieloooooooooooooo" },
    { list: "jelooooooooo" },
    { list: "kelooooooo" },
    { list: "leooo" },
    { list: "melosdsadsado" }
  ]);

  return (
    <Container className="p-3">
      <ListGroup
        className="list_menu"
        horizontal
        style={{
          overflowX: "scroll"
        }}
      >
        <button>+</button>
        {data.map((data, i) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <ListGroup.Item
                className="list_item"
                key={i}
                onClick={() => console.log(data)}
              >
                {data.list}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button> > </button>
      </ListGroup>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

...

working code here https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rgb-koiwf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the requirement. You want the items to have an `onClick` function, for the first item **only** you wan to trigger its `onClick` when....it's rendered?

Comment: I have categories as list item and when I click on each category it displays the items in that category. But when the page renders I only see the categories and have to click on one of them to display it's items. What I want is that whenever the page renders the first category should automatically display it's items. Hope you're able to understand the picture now.

Comment: Ah ok I understand now. However, the answer depends on how you actually display those category items. Are they stored in state too? Can you add the complete, current code you have where you have to click it and then it shows items rather than just `console.log`

Comment: Yes the json looks like this                                                       {[ {category1, [item1, item2]},  {category2, [item3, item4]} ]}

Comment: So first i use map function to display the categories and then use another map function to display the respective items that belongs to that category.

Comment: So I assume the currently selected category is also stored in state. Can you just set its initial value to the first category? e.g.  `const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(category1);`

Comment: I will try to do that thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to do it like this:

```
onClick={() => {
   if(i === 0)
     console.log(data)
}}
```